# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have following lines of code to fetch multiple records using PHP 7.3

```
$query = "Select * from tblorders";         
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();           
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The last line issues as error.

**Error Details**

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll()

I can confirm that the connection is not null and has proper connection details.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hey checkout how it works with mysqli :
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there is no such function! You are mixing PDO and mysqli.

If you want to fetch all records from a mysqli prepared statement you need to do it in two steps. First, fetch the result set using [`mysqli_stmt::get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and then use [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

```
$query = "Select * from tblorders";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

However, I would strongly advise learning PDO instead of mysqli as it is much easier and offers more options.